# Python based regular expression to match twitter usernames from a mixed set of data

Tags: regex-lookarounds

i need a regex code with the help of which i can sort the twitter usernames from a mixed set of data Twitter usernames can contain latin characters, underscores and numbers, and the only limitation is the can be up to 15 characters long. and not more than that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow does not cater to "I need a code" questions that show no code effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@[a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,15}
```

this could possibly be of some help to you